# How to run two forms at startup in winforms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let's consider this scenario: a freshly create windows form application in which I created a Form2 besides the original Form1.

1st Question:
I want both forms to show up at start-up, so i basically wanted to add Application.Run(new Form2()); in main right after the similar command for Form1, but since I read that I can't use multiple threads to run both forms, how do I do it?

2nd Question:
How do I access the form methods from an outside class or even main, since even if I create a form instance I can't seem to access them directly.

3rd Question:
I need to display a buffer of messages in a form, typically I would use a simple text box, but the problem is that I need to add something like a mark as read to all individual messages. Any clues on how to do that?

Comment: Please ask only one question per thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1:  Check out the [ApplicationContext class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(VS.80).aspx).

2:  The methods need to be public but be careful here because you will start having issues with [tight coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)).  For a simple implementation, you'll need to pass references to the calling objects (consider researching the Observer pattern).

3:  Check out a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz(VS.80).aspx).